# The "Comic Sans MS" font is not showing in my Android Delphi application

Tags: delphi, fonts

I wanted to use "Comic Sans MS" font in my android application built in delphi, but in the phone it shows an Arial kind of font. I am new to android.

My button with "Comic Sans MS" font is below:

```
object btnClose: TCornerButton
  DisableFocusEffect = True
  StyledSettings = [FontColor]
  ImageIndex = 0
  Sides = [Top, Left, Bottom, Right]
  Size.PlatformDefault = False
  StyleLookup = 'cornerbuttonstyle'
  TabOrder = 3
  Text = 'Close'
  TextSettings.Font.Family = 'Comic Sans MS'
  TextSettings.Font.Size = 18.000000000000000000
  TextSettings.Font.StyleExt = {00070000000000000004000000}
  XRadius = 3.000000000000000000
  YRadius = 3.000000000000000000
  OnClick = btnCloseClick
end
```

Comment: Probably Comic Sans MS isn't installed on most Android systems. And if the font isn't installed on a device, it cannot be used on that device. (No, fonts are by default not embedded in apps.)

Comment: Comic Sans MS is a Windows font (MS means Microsoft).

Comment: Note you can embed fonts as a resource in Android applications and licenses are available for various Microsoft fonts (~$490US for 50,000 installs for one style of Comic Sans MS with a mobile application license.  Ref: https://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/comic-sans and https://www.fonts.com/content/microsoft-typography).

Comment: As @Brian says, you can embed fonts in an Android application built with Delphi. The font files need to be deployed with a remote path of: ./assets/internal, and the filename without the .ttf extension needs to match the Font.Family value exactly

Comment: ok, so I need to add font  as a resource file in assets/internal folder, without extention. Will try this.